# AddKeyListener via Lambda function

Tags: java, swing, lambda, keylistener

I try to add a KeyListener `KeyTyped` to my JTextField with a lambda function like I did with my action listeners:

```
cmp_btn.addActionListener(e -> actionPerformed(e));
private void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
  // Do something ...
}
```

If I try it with `addKeyListener(e -> keyPerformed(e));` I get the error "lambda parameter provided" but "required type: KeyEvent" in return.

The function is like shown above, but with `KeyEvent e` as parameter.

**// EDIT 1:**
I just saw, that the addKeyListener requires a KeyAdapter. Since KeyAdapter is an abstract class, I need to instantiate a KeyAdapter to make it work, but if I do, then I have the inline function again (which I dont't want, because of reusing the function). Is there a way to extract the defined functions from the inline block?

**// EDIT 2:**
A possible (ugly) solution for the problem would be:

```
cmp_textfield.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
  @Override
  public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)
  {
    super.keyTyped(e);
    My_KeyTyped_Method(e);
  }
});
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, `addKeyListener` takes a `KeyListener` as a parameter. `KeyAdapter` from the other hand created for the reason you created this question. For "simplicity". Take a look at `KeyAdapter`:

```
public abstract class KeyAdapter implements KeyListener {
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {}
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {}
}
```

It implements `KeyListener` and lets you override - target the method you care about. Adding a `KeyListener` with lambdas is impossible since lambdas can be used for `@FunctionalInterface`s only. A `@FunctionalInterface` is the interface that has only one non-`default` method. `KeyListener` interface is not one, since it has 3 methods.

You can't do much about it. One way would be to create `@FunctinalInterface`s by extending `KeyListener` interface and make the "irrelevant"-to-you methods `default`:

An example:

```
@FunctionalInterface //Not required, just a convention
public interface KeyRealeasedListener extends KeyListener {

    @Override
    default void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    default void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    }
}
```

Notice that `keyReleased` is not implemented. And to add it in a component:

```
component.addKeyListener((KeyRealeasedListener) e -> System.out.println("key released"));
```

Comment: Hello George, thank you! I use your solution for solving the problem. It is quite interesting since I work normally in C#. So to make myself understand: Your solution includes the default keyPressed and keyTyped method of the KeyListener class, right? While not defining keyReleased, the addKeyListener construct assumes to call keyReleased, right? If I only use the default method for keyPressed and delete the keyTyped method in the interface, there is no way to use your mentioned idea. Am I right?